# ¿Como puedo crear un array de objetos en PHP?

Tags: php, json, array

Estoy trabajando con una API y necesito crear un array de objetos desde mi código en PHP el array de ejemplo de la API en JSON es así:

```
{ "create": [
    { "name": "Tag1"},
    {  "name": "Tag2"},
    {  "name": "Tag3"} ] }
```

Y mi código de PHP es el siguiente:

```
 $array = array("TAG1", "TAG2", "TAG3");
    $myObj = new stdClass();
    $myObj->name = array();
    for($i=0; $i<count($array); $i++) {
      $myObj->name[$i] =  $array[$i]; }  
    $obj = new stdClass();
    $obj -> create = array($myObj);
    $batch = json_encode($obj);
```

Pero al imprimir el resultado de mi codigo sale asi:

```
{"create":[ 
  {"name":["TAG1,","TAG2,","TAG3"]}
  ]
}
```

¿Como puedo lograr que mi array quede como en el ejemplo de la API?
(Los datos del array no son fijos, varian dependiendo lo que manden los usuarios)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vas bien, simplemente estas asignando el arreglo en el lugar equivocado.
En el ejemplo del API, todo lo que esta encerrado por llaves `{...}` es un objeto,
todo lo que esta encerrado por corchetes `[]` es un arreglo.

Tu ejemplo quedaría de la siguiente manera.

```
    $array = array("TAG1", "TAG2", "TAG3");
    $objects = array();
    for($i=0; $i<count($array); $i++) {
      $myObj = new stdClass();
      $myObj->name = $array[$i];
      $objects[] = $myObj;
    }  
    $obj = new stdClass();
    $obj -> create = array($objects);
    $batch = json_encode($obj);
```

Comment: Gracias!! me funciono perfectamente!